# How to launch executables in parallel on CentOS?

Tags: centos

I need to run several executables in parallel from  terminal (ssh). They all must have same home dir (not /).

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and execute a bash script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
executable-1 &
executable-2 &
...
```

Comment: thanks. Can i add a question to that: where can i read documentation on daemon function that is used for that purpose in service launch scripts?